# Is it legal to have many websites of the same company?

Tags: seo

I know companies who have 3 websites with different name and URL. All these 3 **websites are ranked in the first and 2nd page of google search results**, and they don't let other companies share the first place and have **clean competition**.
So, is it an illegal use to report these sites to google?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, it's perfectly legal, this occurs because the company has different websites for different countries - they may not be VERY different but are different enough that google ranks them separately.

The only law in question here is civil, not criminal so nothing is outright illegal.

Comment: @paulmorriss "different websites for different countries"

Comment: it's for the some language, i explaine :
the real name of the company is : foodcompany.com
and others website for the some company ie:
food-for-free.com
best-food-on-the-net.com
fast-food-best-com
all the website have key-words included in it's URL, and all are linked to each others.
so, the user who search for a key word : "best food", can found in the first page or second page, all the 3 URL, with different prices, so 
if we have 2 company x 3 website = 6 + 2 real company url = 8
that's mean 90% of the search results are for only two company!
---hop u understand my english---

Comment: @Gadiri What do you mean by saying  "different websites for different countries"? Do you want me to put that in the question?